# XCPlayground framework alternative for ios

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I wants to use showing live views functionality of XCPlayground framework for ios playground.
This framework is for osx playground. 
Does any one knows what is the alternative for ios [image]

This is for OSX So what is for ios

Comment: There's a discussion about this in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/27jmuk/playground_problem_replacement_for_xcplayground/), and the consensus seems to be that it's not currently possible.

Comment: it is just not released to us yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode 6 beta 3 (6A254o), posted 07.07.2014, brings iOS support to XCPlayground.

The new (as of this post) version can be downloaded with an active Apple Developer account by navigating to https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action, pressing "iOS 8 beta 3" and then pressing "Download Xcode".

As an aside, you can become familiar with XCPlayground by downloading & reading this PDF form Apple: http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/408xxcm26svis12/408/408_swift_playgrounds.pdf?dl=1

Comment: Note: This beta does not has `XCPShowView` function yet.

Answer (score 1):

As of XCode 8, the framework is now named `PlaygroundSupport`, works both for iOS and MacOS (XCode doesn't auto-complete it btw).

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 10.2 there's a **PlaygroundSupport** framework that works for **macOS** and **iOS**. It shares a playground data, manages live views, and controls the execution of a playground.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
```

You can use Playground Support from within playgrounds to:

- Access a playground page and manage its execution
- Access and share persistent data
- Assess the progress of the learner, update hints, and show success text

> You also can use `PlaygroundSupport` to display and dismiss live views, which show the results of running the code in a playground. You can create live views for your own types by leveraging the built-in live view representations available on many existing types. Traditional live views are available in playgrounds in Xcode and in Swift Playgrounds. They run in the same process as the code in the playground, so you can access their properties and methods as usual; however, they're reset each time you run the playground. The always-on live view in Swift Playgrounds, activated when you add LiveView.swift to a page, executes in its own process so you can persist information and visuals between successive runs. The always-on live view isn't reset until you leave the page.